# Remove [ ' ' ] from a string in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know how to remove for example only `[`, but how can I do for remove multiple things?

I have to remove 3 things, the two `'`, the `[` & `]` and the space

The string when I print it's something like this: `[ 'Chroma 2 Case' ]`

Thank you so much!

Comment: I discovered why returns [" "] it's because is a stringfy array. How can I convert it to a string?

Comment: what? can you please EDIT your question and clarify it with some examples of inputs and what is the expected output for each example?

Answer (score 1):

u can either use slice function i.e using

```
var s1 = "this is a test string.";
s1.slice(3, s1.length-3);
```

or you can either replace the extra string ([, ], ', ......) using regex

```
s1.replace(^\[\s'(.*)'\s\]$/, '$1');
```

Comment: I discovered why returns [" "] it's because is a stringfy array. How can I convert it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use RegEx to remove the braces and quotations.

```
var newstring = oldstring.replace(/[\[\]']/gi, '');
```

To remove whitespace, use `newstring = newstring.trim();`

Comment: this will remove esaped apostrophes and [] inside the string

Comment: @user93 you didn't restore the correct version unfortunately, I rolled back to the 1st version (which was edited by cktang within 5 minutes from the version that you tried to improve, so your improvement was completely different) => please post your answer separately

Comment: I agree @Aprillion sorry for the nuisance

Comment: I discovered why returns [" "] it's because is a stringfy array. How can I convert it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regular expression and use the first capture group (the insides of first round parentheses) as `$1` in `string.replace` function, e.g.:

```
"[ 'Chroma 2 Case' ]".replace(/^\[\s*'(.*)'\s*\]$/, '$1')
```

explanation: https://regex101.com/r/TGWCVn/1

P.S.: also works for strings with escaped apostrophes like `[ 'Chroma 2\' Case' ]`

**edit**: if needed to support various quotes:

```
'["StatTrak™ R8 Revolver | Crimson Web (Battle-Scarred)"]'.replace(
  /^\[\s*['"](.*)['"]\s*\]$/,
  '$1'
)
```

**edit2**: if you have an array and not a string, to get the 1st item:

```
["StatTrak™ R8 Revolver | Crimson Web (Battle-Scarred)"][0]
```

Comment: Now it returns this ["StatTrak™ R8 Revolver | Crimson Web (Battle-Scarred)"]

Comment: not sure what you mean exactly, but I updated my answer if you need to extract `["..."]` as well and not just single quotes... if you mean something else, please create a new question

Answer (score 0):

You can split on the quotes, providing that you aren't expecting any more in the string

```
 const test = "[ \'Chroma 2 Case\' ]"
 test.split('\'')[1]
```

Demo at: https://repl.it/JTIx/1

Comment: this will get only a part of string if there are nested (escaped) apostrophes `\'`

Comment: Now it returns this ["StatTrak™ R8 Revolver | Crimson Web (Battle-Scarred)"]

Answer (score 0):

Using the replace method on any string with regular expression. In your case:

```
let originalString = "[ 'Chroma 2 Case' ]"; 
let newString = originalString.replace(/[\[\]\'\s]/g, '');
```

Usually you would use trim() on a string to just remove whitespace, however since you're already using a regex for `[`, `]`, and `'`, the `\s` in the matching regex takes care of any spaces, too.

Comment: this will remove spaces around `2`

Answer (score 0):

I used `.toString()` and now it works.